# GET max value form since DB symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Sorry to disturb you but I would like to obtain a max value for a form validation for example it can be a numeric field but the validation of type range MaxValue will have to be retrieved in the database I explain myself for example I wish to reserve a transport the max value by default is 4 for 4 remaining places but if for this vehicle there are 3 places left, the validation would have to pass to 3

I tried to go through entitytype with events but it didn't change anything to my problem it returned in the drop down list all the number of places for each vehicle.

The goal is to make a simple form a reservation button with just a way to choose the number of places while not being able to exceed the value of the database.

For example the URL is /transport/6/book

We must find a way to pass the value of id number 6 and the validation would be between 1 and 3 for example or create a list that puts 1 2 3

If transport 7 to 1 place of availability it would have to be 1 only.

Excuse me if I misspoke but I've been working on it for more than a week and I can't get it to work so I've moved to an old commit to keep the application working.
I'm a beginner in this area so I don't know the advanced features of the form but I'm very good at the twig repository etc. It's just this part that is blocking, thanks in advance for your help.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nbPlaces', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Transport::class,
                'label' => 'Nombre de places',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => "Nombre de places",
                ],
                'query_builder' => function (TransportRepository $transportRepository) use ($id_service) {
                    return $transportRepository->findOneByIdPlace($id_service);
                },
                'choice_label' => 'nbPlaces'
            ]);
    }

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Reservation::class,
        'id_service' => null
    ]);
}
```

and controller

```
$booking = new Reservation();
        $form = $this->createForm(ReservationType::class, $booking, ['id_service' => $service]);
```

and $id_service is undefined variable in use

Comment: I've delete anwser is suppose.. and edit post but not found my anwser and i search more 1 wekk (soory for m'y english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `$id_service` is never defined. You should get it from the options. Take a look here :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#other-common-form-features

So your code should be a thing like this.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $id_service = $options['id_service'];
    $builder
        ->add('nbPlaces', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Transport::class,
            'label' => 'Nombre de places',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => "Nombre de places",
            ],
            'query_builder' => function (TransportRepository $transportRepository) use ($id_service) {
                return $transportRepository->findOneByIdPlace($id_service);
            },
            'choice_label' => 'nbPlaces'
        ]);
}
```

Comment: I have Return value of App\Repository\TransportRepository::findOneByIdPlace() must be an instance of App\Entity\Transport or null, array returned on error  for ` public function findOneByIdPlace($service): ?Transport
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('t.nbPlaces')
            ->andWhere('t.service = :service')
            ->setParameter('service', $service)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
   }`

Comment: So I think the first issue is solved, this is a completely new and maybe you should have created another question.
You have 
- `EntityType` as FormType
-  `?Transport` as method returned type
so why do you only select `t.nbPlaces` ? And why use `andWhere` althrough you only have one criteria ? 
Why is this named `IdPlace` and `Transport::$service` ?

Comment: id service_id lieu_depart lieu_arrivee date_heure_rdv nb_places is names of different column and would like detect nb_places remaining in form

Comment: Please just create a new question with the Entity's and the repository's code. This is unreadable (and close this one).

Comment: I have success get value from db for exemple is 4 but how to add in listbox 1, 2 , 3 ,

Comment: Your form child `nbPlaces` is declared as you will give it an `Transport` entity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60342282/loop-for-in-type-querybuilder-symfony-4-select-option-choice i have detail it